# Unable to retrive data from firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
public class Userprofile extends Fragment {

    private FragmentUserprofileBinding binding;

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    FirebaseDatabase db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = FragmentUserprofileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        View root = binding.getRoot();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_userprofile, container, false);

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        String x= phoneNoClass.getMobileNoOfDoctor();

        binding.logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                firebaseAuth.signOut();
            }
        });

        DatabaseReference roat=db.getReference("DoctorData").child("+919937336406");

        roat.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {

            @Override

            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()){

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "updating....."+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    String uname=String.valueOf(task.getResult().child("name").getValue());

                    binding.UserName.setText(uname);

                }else {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "unable"+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered? Do you get any Toast message?

Comment: yes it is showing toast(updating...) but do not retriving data

Comment: If you try to log the value of `uname`, what do you get printed out?

Comment: yes result is showing in log but not in app

Comment: Is `UserName` the correct TextView?

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: If you use `binding.UserName.setText("Test");` is the hard coded String displayed?

Comment: after using binding.UserName.setText("Test"); also it is showing nothing

Comment: In that case, that's not a Firebase issue, but a TextView one. Can you show us the layout file that contains that TextView?

Comment: see in answer section i have already post it

Comment: Have you tried to use findViewById instead of using that binding object?

Comment: yeah,now it is working... Thanks a ton

Comment: I'll write an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> yes the result is showing in the log but not in the app.

The problem isn't related to Firebase, it's a problem related to the way you are using data binding. So the simplest solution is to use View's [findViewById(int id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)) method to refer to your `UserName` TextView.